# How to use a second data source in spring?

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, spring-repositories

I downloaded the example code here

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources

but I still don't understand how an repository is connected to a datasource. Even when I look into the config class, it makes no reference to a repository. And inside the repository interface it makes no reference to the data source or config.

So when you use two different repositories to save, how does it know which datasource to go to for each repo?

Comment: I think because of package component scan that is defined in each config class

Answer (score 0):

In the repository with examples you linked, each config class is annotated with `@EnableJpaRepositories` that does scanning for repositories only in the package of annotated class plus subpackages - this is where the relation between datasource and repository happens.

Comment: So repos are configured based on a Config class in the same package? That's so weird design, why? What if I have repos spread across a lot of different packages? I Have to create a config for each one even though I want them all to use the same one? If I don't create a config, does it somehow uses a default?

Answer (score 0):

Notice the configurations (commented as /* important */)

in [OrderConfig](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/multiple-datasources/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/multipleds/order/OrderConfig.java)

```java
@Configuration

/* important */
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "orderEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "orderTransactionManager")

class OrderConfig {

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager orderTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(orderEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean orderEntityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        /* important */
        factoryBean.setDataSource(orderDataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(OrderConfig.class.getPackage().getName());

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource orderDataSource() {

        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().//
                setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).//
                setName("orders").//
                build();
    }
}
```

and, [CustomerConfig](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/multiple-datasources/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/multipleds/customer/CustomerConfig.java)

```java
@Configuration

/* important */
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "customerEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "customerTransactionManager")

class CustomerConfig {

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager customerTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(customerEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean customerEntityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        /* important */
        factoryBean.setDataSource(customerDataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(CustomerConfig.class.getPackage().getName());

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource customerDataSource() {

        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().//
                setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).//
                setName("customers").//
                build();
    }
}
```

and, finally the `@Transactional` annotation in [DataInitializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/multiple-datasources/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/multipleds/DataInitializer.java)

```java
/* important */
@Transactional("customerTransactionManager")

public CustomerId initializeCustomer() {
    return customers.save(new Customer("Dave", "Matthews")).getId();
}
```

uses `customerTransactionManager` which is configured in `CustomerConfig`

and,

```java
/* important */
@Transactional("orderTransactionManager")

public Order initializeOrder(CustomerId customer) {

   Assert.notNull(customer, "Customer identifier must not be null!");

   Order order = new Order(customer);
   order.add(new LineItem("Lakewood Guitar"));

   return orders.save(order);
}
```

uses `orderTransactionManager` which is configured in `OrderConfig`

Basically, you're configuring different `datasources`, different `entityManagers`, different `transactionManagers` and refer to them specifically as per your choice.

Comment: So repos are configured based on a Config class in the same package? That's so weird design, why? What if I have repos spread across a lot of different packages? I Have to create a config for each one even though I want them all to use the same one? If I don't create a config, does it somehow uses a default?